# Gitlab runner docker compose: not found

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I have registered gitlab-runner with the following command:

```
gitlab-runner register --non-interactive \
  --url ${URL} \
  --registration-token ${REGISTRATION_TOKEN} \
  --description ${RUNNER_NAME} \
  --tag-list ${TAGS} \
  --executor "docker" \
  --docker-image="docker:stable" \
  --docker-pull-policy if-not-present \
  --locked=false \
  --docker-privileged=true \
  --docker-volumes=["/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock", "/cache"] \
```

There is my runner config:

```
[[runners]]
  name = "XXX"
  url = "XXX"
  id = 19981753
  token = "XXX"
  token_obtained_at = 2022-12-24T11:43:10Z
  token_expires_at = 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.cache]
    MaxUploadedArchiveSize = 0
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
    [runners.cache.azure]
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "docker:stable"
    privileged = true
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache", "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"]
    pull_policy = ["if-not-present"]
    shm_size = 0
```

Then I am trying to run ci with docker-compose, but there is an error: docker-compose: not found:
[image]

There is a part from my .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
before_script:
  - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY

stages:
  - build
  - staging
  - release
  - deploy


build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "IMAGE_APP_TAG=$STAGE_IMAGE_APP_TAG" >> .env
    - docker-compose build
    - docker-compose push
  only:
    - dev
    - main
```

Which image for docker executor should i use to run docker-compose? Should i change .gitlac-ci.yml or gitlab-runner config.toml?

Comment: your docker runner is using as a default the image `docker:stable` this image does not have docker-compose in it. You will need to use either a different image for the job, or change the default image for the runner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the buid job, just add the docker compose image

```yaml
build:
  image: docker/compose
```

Or you can use any other image and install the docker compose by yourself.